# ¿Cómo solucionar la excepción "JSONException: End of input at character 0 of" en Volley?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley, jsonobject, requests

Estoy consumiendo un **API REST (UPDATE)** desarrollado en Oracle APEX desde Android usando Volley a través de un objeto **JsonObjectRequest** usando el metodo **Request.Method.PUT**.

Para mi fortuna el ***API se consume exitosamente*** y me actualiza la información en la base de datos, logro capturar mi *status_code* en el parseNetworkResponse pero no en el onResponse y mi petición está generando una **JSONException** que no he podido corregir

[image: salida por consola]

Mi API REST con APEX para realizar el UPDATE y enviar el status_code = 201

[image: API REST PUT]

```
  public void updateCategoria(Context applicationContext, VolleyResponse volleyResponse){

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("id", 1);
        jsonObject.put("name", "Actualizado 2");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // JSONException
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, json_url_update, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Log.w("Response VOLLEY SC", response.toString());
                        if(statusCode == 201){
                            Log.w("Response VOLLEY CODE", "RESPUESTA EXITOSA");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception VOLLEY", "Error en el updateCategoria " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            volleyResponse.onError(error, error.getMessage());
            Log.e("onErrorResponse VOLLEY",  error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            statusCode = response.statusCode;
            Log.w("STATUS CODE RESPONSE: ", ""+statusCode);
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };

    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: Revisa el Logcat de Android, para ver lo que estás obteniendo aquí: `Log.w("Response VOLLEY SC", response.toString());` y agrégalo a la pregunta. Puede que estés recibiendo un JSON inválido.

Comment: Es la primera imagen, la mas pequeña, los Log que están dentro del método sobreescrito public void onResponse(JSONObject response) no se muestran, automáticamente está entrando al  public void onErrorResponse

Comment: Primeramente, se agradece que en vez de imágenes pongas el texto con los mensajes de error, así es más fácil de analizar. Luego, no entiendo del todo cuál es el problema. Qué quieres decir con esto: *Para mi fortuna el API se consume exitosamente y me actualiza la información en la base de datos, logro capturar mi status_code en el parseNetworkResponse pero no en el onResponse y mi petición está generando una JSONException que no he podido corregir* Tu petición está entrando en el bloque de error probablemente porque no recibe respuesta. ¿El problema es manejando los errores o cuál es en sí?